# WordPress administrator user should not be logged into WooCommerce account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Administrator user can only customize themes. I am using `wp_set_auth_cookie()` for auto login and I don't need any other admin pages.
When theme customize, administrator user details showing in my account page. Is it possible to restrict administrator login in WooCommerce my account page?

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_theme_customization' );

function my_theme_customization()
{
    global $pagenow;
    if ($pagenow !== 'customize.php' && is_admin()) {
        header('Location:' . site_url());
        exit;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question to be a little more clear? Right now it's confusing - for example Administrators can do anything, not sure why you're trying to restrict them.

Comment: You can create a new role instead of restricting admin and set capabilities as you need

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it something like

```
function iconic_login_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    if ( check user permissions ) {
        //redirect the admin to another page 
    }

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'iconic_login_redirect' );
```

I am not using wordpress from last 2 years, so you may like to look into line 1005 of `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php`

Answer (score 0):

I understand you should not mess with administrator privileges. Instead, you can create new user type with access as you want, and assign it to respective users.

You can create new user type under Users --> Capabilities in WordPress admin page.

Hope this will help you.